# How to provide an access token when playing a video in a youtube iframe?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a youtube account with several subscription channels, one of which is paid (PiXL). I am able to successfully retrieve the list of subscribed channels, including PiXL, and the metadata for all of the available videos.

I am using the YT.player (iframe API) to play the videos. When I try to play a PiXL movie, I see an offer to subscribe to the channel instead of the player window.

Is there a way to provide the access token to the YT.player so that the player knows I am authorized to play the video?